# "newListener" event is not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, node-modules, event-listener

I am trying to experiment with some node event code.

Below is the code, based on the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener) "newListener" should fire every time before a listener is added to its internal array of listeners, But its not working as expected.

Node version - v6.11.0

```
var event = require("events");
var events = new event.EventEmitter();

function FunHello(){
    console.log("Hello World !!!!!!!!");
}

function FunGreet(){
    console.log("Good Morning !!!!!!!!");
}

events.on("sayHello",FunHello);

events.on("sayHello",FunGreet);

events.addListener("hello",function(){
    console.log("hello hello !!!!");
});

/****** newListener is added *********/
events.on("newListener", function (evtName, fn) {
   console.log("New Listener: " + evtName);
});

events.emit("sayHello");

console.log("No of listerns for the event sayHello : " + events.listenerCount("sayHello"));

events.emit("hello");
```

The code is available on https://repl.it/Iqe4/0

Comment: Does it work if you move the newListener code above the other addListener calls?

Comment: oh yes, it works. cool....... So it has to be above all event listeners right ?

Comment: Of course, the event fires when the listener is added. There's no `newListener` handler when you attach the `hello` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is that in the output you are not getting output of `newListener` event. I tried moving the `newListener` code block above all the other event listeners and it is giving the desired output.

Here is the code below:

```
var event = require("events");
var events = new event.EventEmitter();

function FunHello(){
    console.log("Hello World !!!!!!!!");
}

function FunGreet(){
    console.log("Good Morning !!!!!!!!");
}

events.on("newListener", (evtName,fn)=>{
    console.log("New Listener: " + evtName);
 });


events.on("sayHello",FunHello);

events.on("sayHello",FunGreet);

events.addListener("hello",function(){
    console.log("hello hello !!!!");
});
events.emit("sayHello");

console.log("No of listerns for the event sayHello : " + events.listenerCount("sayHello"));

events.emit("hello");
```